# How to do commenting in emberjs script handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, sproutcore, handlebars.js

Can anybody tell me how to include commented code in emberjs handlebars templates?

```
  <script id="restaurantDetail" data-template-name='restaurantDetail' type="text/x-handlebars">
//Commented code goes here
</script>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the looks of the [github page](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/), you want `{{! comment text here}}`:

> **Comments**
>
> You can add comments to your templates with the following syntax.
>
> ```
> {{! This is a comment }}
> ```
>
> You can also use real html comments if you want them to end up in the output.
>
> ```
> <div>
>     {{! This comment will not end up in the output }}
>     <!-- This comment will show up in the output -->
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Also, if you're using real html comments and want to include variables, make sure to use the [unbound helper](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Handlebars.helpers&method=.unbound&src=false) `<!-- Item {{unbound itemId}} -->`

Comment: Are comments required to be in their own {{ }} container or are they allowed to be inline, such as {{name !this is App.controller.content.name}}?

Comment: I find if I put in real html comments the ember-cli complains about them as being "unexpected" and spits them out all in the console

Answer (score 27):

I recommend using `{{!--   comment here  --}}` because this comment syntax can contain new lines and also `}}` inside the comment, for example:

```
Bad comments:
    {{! badly commented {{if somecondition "red" "blue" }} }}  
    {{! badly multiline comments
        another line  }}  

Comment that works:
    {{!-- this is commented correctly {{if somecondition "red" "blue" }} --}}
    {{!-- correct multiline comments
        another line  --}}
```

(I know this is an old question, but this answer appears first on Google when searching for ember template comments, so I wanted to help future readers)

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, helped me a great deal while learning Ember ( just make sure you don't litter your templates with commented out code :) )

Comment: This was probably added in later versions? As the accepted answer is from 2012 and this is from 2015